# Rename files with given names in python

Tags: python, rename

[PYTHON]
Hi everyone, I have a problem to solve. I have two folders like this

FOLDER 1:

- 05.xml
- 06.xml
- 07.xml
- 08.xml

FOLDER 2:

- 01_2500.jpeg
- 02_2501.jpeg
- 03_2502.jpeg
- 04_2503.jpeg
- 05_2504.jpeg
- 06_2505.jpeg
- 07_2506.jpeg
- 08_2507.jpeg

I need to rename the folder 1 as follows:

- 2504.xml
- 2505.xml
- 2506.xml
- 2507.xml

How can I do it? I have been trying this for days. Obviously this is a simplified example, because there are actually thousands of files to rename.

I thought that I could use split function for the folder 2 and then apply if, but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a lookup from the files in folder 2, and then apply `os.rename` by iterating over the contents of folder 1. The dictionary created from files in folder store store the leading digit as its key, and the trailing four digit run as a value:

```
import os, re
renames = dict(re.findall('\d+', i) for i in os.listdir('/folder2'))
for i in os.listdir('/folder1'):
   os.rename(i, re.sub('\d+(?=\.xml)', lambda x:renames[x.group()], i)
```